# The Cryolator disappears after using the Dogmeat glitch

Tags: fallout-4

Inside Vault 111, I asked Dogmeat to fetch items near where the Cryolator is stored. However, when Dogmeat retrieves the Cryolator, it disappears when he drops it. Is the Cryolator lost, or can I still get it somehow?

Answer (score 4):

This was a reported bug, as of patch 1.34. If you used the glitch on console, and the gun glitched out, I'm afraid it's gone. If you happen to be playing on PC, you might consider using console commands to give yourself one, instead.

> ### Bugs
>
> - Dogmeat can no longer be ordered to get the weapon after the 1.34 update. Doing so will glitch the game and Dogmeat will either grab a pipe gun or a combat shotgun and sometimes nothing and the Cryolator will disappear. <sup>[verified]</sup>
>   [***- "Cryolator (Fallout 4) @ Fallout Fandom***](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Cryolator_(Fallout_4))

*Roddy of the Frozen Peas* reports that, at least as of 11/7/2020, you can't physically take Dogmeat into Vault 111. This was likely patched in to prevent both the original exploit, and the resulting glitch that occurred past patch 1.34.

---

### Obtaining the Cryonator

- You can open the container, yourself, once you gain rank 3 in the Locksmith perk. This perk requires 4 perception, a player level of 18, and the two preceding Locksmith perks before being unlocked.
- If you have Cait as a companion, she can pick the lock. You may need to give her a number of bobby pins for her to open the lock.
- If you have the *"Automatron"* addon, you can upgrade robot companions with a lockpick module, which gives them the same lockpicking ability as Cait. The lockpick module requires 4 adhesive, 2 aluminium, 1 ceramic, 2 circuitry and 3 rubber and must be crafted from a robot workbench.
- If you are playing the game on PC (and not in Survival mode), you can just give yourself the gun via console commands. Press the <kbd>~</kbd> button to bring up the console, and enter the command `player.addItem 00171B2B 1`. This should add one Cryolator to your inventory. You will likely also need ammo, which you can add with `player.additem 0018ABE2 X`. Replace `X` with how every many cryo cells you want.

Answer (score 0):

Get Dogmeat to grab it then leave the vault before he has time to give it to you then it'll be in his inventory. I don't know if they tried to patch it or what but it used to work but I haven't played in 2 years.

Comment: The Dogmeat Cryolator glitch has been patched for years. You can't take him into Vault 111 anymore. (Source: I just tried it about 2 hours ago.)

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Dogmeat I tried this once and he will grab a pipe pistol or a shotgun but will never grab the cryolator. To fix this leave him in Sanctuary and go to Combat Zone and get Cait and give her all your lockpicks you might have to use the Lockpick cheat but she will open the safe and you can get it.